# Why `n % int(m) != n % float(m)`?

Tags: python, modulus

Why modulus is different for the same number with the same divider only that represented as `float` and `int`? Or eg. why `10**23 % int(9)` != `10**23 % float(9)`?

```
for i in range(1, 30):
   print(i, 10**i % 9, 10**i % 9.0)
```

Outputs:

```
1 1 1.0
2 1 1.0
3 1 1.0
4 1 1.0
5 1 1.0
6 1 1.0
7 1 1.0
8 1 1.0
9 1 1.0
10 1 1.0
11 1 1.0
12 1 1.0
13 1 1.0
14 1 1.0
15 1 1.0
16 1 1.0
17 1 1.0
18 1 1.0
19 1 1.0
20 1 1.0
21 1 1.0
22 1 1.0
23 1 5.0    <--- Why?  10**23 % 9 != 10**23 % 9.0
24 1 0.0    And so on in no particular order.
25 1 1.0
26 1 6.0
27 1 1.0
28 1 2.0
29 1 1.0
```

Python 3.8.1

Comment: Worth a read [Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html)

Answer (score 4):

To perform `10**23%9.0`, the value `10**23` is converted to a float. Floats are approximations. The value you actually get if you represent `10**23` as a float is quite a way off the precise value.

```
>>> x = float(10**23)
>>> int(x)
99999999999999991611392
```

Answer (score 0):

Floating point precision error. As you get further away from zero, floating point loses accuracy in the single digits, which is what modulus shows.

We can show this by converting the large int `10**i` to float and back, and the comparing it to the original int value:

```
>>> for i in range(1, 30):
...    print(i, 10**i, int(float(10**i)) - 10**i)
... 
1 10 0
2 100 0
3 1000 0
4 10000 0
5 100000 0
6 1000000 0
7 10000000 0
8 100000000 0
9 1000000000 0
10 10000000000 0
11 100000000000 0
12 1000000000000 0
13 10000000000000 0
14 100000000000000 0
15 1000000000000000 0
16 10000000000000000 0
17 100000000000000000 0
18 1000000000000000000 0
19 10000000000000000000 0
20 100000000000000000000 0
21 1000000000000000000000 0
22 10000000000000000000000 0
23 100000000000000000000000 -8388608
24 1000000000000000000000000 -16777216
25 10000000000000000000000000 905969664
26 100000000000000000000000000 4764729344
27 1000000000000000000000000000 13287555072
28 10000000000000000000000000000 -416880263168
29 100000000000000000000000000000 -8566849142784
```

Comment: Justify why you think it is due to rounding rather than limit of precision.(your example shows truncation rather than rounding)

Answer (score 0):

Floating point precision. When you do modulus with a float, the value gets converted to a float, and 10^23 happens to be larger than floats can represent naturally. We can see exactly what's happening using `Decimal`:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> (sign, mantissa, exponent) = Decimal(10**23).as_tuple()
>>> sign, mantissa, exponent
(0, (1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 0)
>>> (sign, mantissa, exponent) = Decimal(float(10**23)).as_tuple()
>>> sign, mantissa, exponent
(0, (9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 1, 6, 1, 1, 3, 9, 2), 0)
```